# Regex To Extract Second Line

Tags: .net, regex, webharvy

Tool Used - WebHarvy
REgex Flavor - .NET

Looking for an expression to extract the second line (address) from following blocks of text

```
Company: Acme associates & sons
99122 W. Charleston Blvd., Suite 555, Las Vegas, NV 89135
Phone : (702) 123-4567
Fax : (702) 123-4567
Email : email@example.com
```

Used the following expression, but it didn't work

```
(.*)(?=(\n.*){3}$)
```

Please advise

Comment: Doesn't `^.*\n(.*)` work for you? Or to make sure the lines are not empty: `^.+\n(.+)`. BTW, what do you mean by "didn't work"? How did it work?

Comment: Why use regex at all?  It's `input.Split('\n')[1]`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Because the regex is used in a tool, not in .NET code.

Comment: @RamanSahasi Anyway, it would be nice to hear from OP how the original pattern failed.

Comment: @blackystart: do you mean your regex only returned the *first* line?

Comment: @blackystrat Are you sure the tool uses .NET regex flavor? If it is using ECMAScript 5, you should use something like `^.*\r?\n(.*)` or `^.*[\r\n]+(.*)`

Comment: the first line that doesn't contain `:` ? [`(?m)^[^:]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/n1TmuE/1)

Comment: Hi Wiktor - what I meant by 'doesn't work' is that when I used that expression, it fetched the following 

`Company: Acme associates & sons
Fax : (702) 123-4567`

It fetched the first and fourth line

Comment: So, my assumption is correct and you should use my example regex.

Comment: @blackystrat See my answer explaining this confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that WebHarvey will return all capturing groups there are defined in the regex pattern. It means you may use any of these

```
^.*\r?\n(.*)
```

Or

```
(?<=^.*\r?\n)(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.*%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%28.*%29&i=Company%3A%20Jason%20Awad%20%26%20Associates%0D%0A10801%20W.%20Charleston%20Blvd.%2C%20Suite%20575%2C%20Las%20Vegas%2C%20NV%2089135%0D%0APhone%20%3A%20%28702%29%20732-4141%0D%0AFax%20%3A%20%28702%29%20732-8449%0D%0AEmail%20%3A%20jason%40jasonawad.com%20)

You should not blindly test the regexps at the online regex testers. Note that RegexStorm will show a two-line match for [`^.*\r?\n(.*)` pattern](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.*%5Cr%3F%5Cn%28.*%29&i=Company%3A%20Jason%20Awad%20%26%20Associates%0D%0A10801%20W.%20Charleston%20Blvd.%2C%20Suite%20575%2C%20Las%20Vegas%2C%20NV%2089135%0D%0APhone%20%3A%20%28702%29%20732-4141%0D%0AFax%20%3A%20%28702%29%20732-8449%0D%0AEmail%20%3A%20jason%40jasonawad.com%20), but look what you get in the Group 1:

[image]

That is what WebHarvey will return. See the [WebHarvey docs](https://www.webharvy.com/articles/regex.html):

> WebHarvy will extract only those portion(s) of the main text which matches the group(s) specified in the RegEx string.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - the first line
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line ending
- `(.*)` - Line #2 (empty or not, if you need a non-empty line, use `.+`).

The `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind that requires a first line before the matched second line here, but in WebHarvey, you do not need that.

Comment: `(?<=^.*\r?\n)(.*)` works for [webscraper.io](https://www.webscraper.io/web-scraper-first-time-install)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
^.+?[\r\n]+(.+?)[\r\n]
```

The match is in group 1.

Comment: Hi Derek - it fetched the first and second lines

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.%2b%3f%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28.%2b%3f%29%5b%5cr%5cn%5d&i=Company%3a+Jason+Awad+%26+Associates%0d%0a10801+W.+Charleston+Blvd.%2c+Suite+575%2c+Las+Vegas%2c+NV+89135%0d%0aPhone+%3a+%28702%29+732-4141%0d%0aFax+%3a+%28702%29+732-8449%0d%0aEmail+%3a+jason%40jasonawad.com+